# Drupal 8 Groups module make a view of nodes that are within the group the logged in member is a member of

Tags: drupal-8

This is a Drupal 8 question related to the Groups module (not Organic Groups).

I have a Group which has a user associated to it along with several nodes. I'd like to create a view that lists all the nodes in the logged in users group but am struggling to get the relationships right.

Thanks,
Bez

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the answer to this elsewhere - https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/2793631#comment-13618168 (comment 14)

Add these relationships to your view, in this order:

1. "Group content for Content" (in the "Group Content" category). You can select your content type(s) under "filter by plugin" if you want to limit what content should be available (although if your view is already filtering by content type, I think that will accomplish the same thing).
2. "Group - The group containing the entity." (also under the Group Content category, not available before adding the first relationship.) It will automatically have a relationship to "Content group content".
3. "Group content - Relate to the group content entities. From there you can relate to the actual grouped entities." (in the "Group" category.) Under "filter by plugin", select "Group membership".
4. "User from group content - Relates to the User entity the group content represents." - in the User category. (Don't get it confused with "User" in the Group or Group Content categories). Important: for this relationship, you have to choose the correct relationship, which is "Group content", NOT "Content group content" (should be the second in the "Relationships" dropdown when you configure this relationship.) Next, select "Group membership" under "filter by plugin" (it should be the only option).

Next, add a "User ID" contextual filter. It should have the "Group content User" relationship by default. Under "When the filter value is NOT in the URL" select "Provide default value", and for Type, select "User ID from logged in user".

Voila, when you test your view in the preview by entering the user IDs you should see only content from the group(s) that user is a member of. (Make sure you have some content and users added to different groups for testing).

Thanks

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your answer is self contained, see ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and ["barely more than a link to an external site"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). What is in comment 14?